# Caja de busqueda al estilo de youtube (en el centro)

Tags: html, css

El caso es que estoy intenando alinear un logo (en formato de texto) y un input [image: imagen del sitio]

El logo (ScriptsHub) ya esta en su sitio, lo que estoy intentando es centrar el input, es decir, que quede algo asi:
[image: youtube]

Pueden ver el progreso de scriptshub y el codigo fuente entrando en: https://scriptshub.yzde.es/

Comment: Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score -3):

Prueba agregando en la clase sidenav align-items: center

También revisa esto:
https://lenguajecss.com/css/maquetacion-y-colocacion/flexbox/

Suerte

Comment: Gracias! Lo estoy mirando lo del flex, ahora os cuento. :D

Comment: Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción.

Comment: Le di la respuesta al usuario, y le pasé un enlace donde ampliaba la información ya que tenía dudas con flex. No entiendo cuál sería el problema de llevarlo a otro sitio, pensé que era más importante compartir el conocimiento, pero lo tendré en cuenta.

Comment: @EFF el problema no es llevarlo a otro sitio, lo hacemos mucho para enviarlos a página oficiales de los distintos lenguajes de programación que aquí se abordan. El problema es que las respuestas, al igual que las preguntas, deben ser autocontenidas, y deben poderse entender por si solas sin salir del sitio, y en todo caso, tal como bien dices, ampliar la información externamente si hace falta. En este caso has contestado hablando de una clase **sidenav** que no se ve en la pregunta, porque no es autocontenida, y quizás lo has encontrado en su enlace, pero sin abrirlo no se entiende tu respuest

Comment: @EFF por lo tanto, tanto la pregunta como tu respuesta carecen de sentido si el enlace inicial desaparece con el tiempo (algo muy habitual) y eso es lo que han querido decir con esa respuesta automática (es un texto preestablecido que puede no ser exacto en tu caso pero apunta al problema que acabo de describirte)